# Wiring an ammeter with no shunt

Tags: current-measurement

I am new to electronics and trying to make something easy to start with.
Bought one of those voltmeter and ammeter AIO from ebay ([LINK](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/301102070140?_trksid=p2059210.m2749.l2649&var=600212373783&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT) , see item #5) and want to hook it to a 12V battery (4Ah) to measure how many amps a 12V monitor draws and to monitor battery voltage.

Specs:

```
Operating voltage: DC 4.5 ~ 30V. 
Measure voltage: DC 0 ~ 100V.
Minimum resolution (V): 0.1V. 
Measure accuracy: 1% (± 1 digit). 
Minimum resolution (A): 0.01A. 
Operating Current: <20mA. 
Measure current: 10A (direct measurement, built-in shunt).
```

It has 5 wires:

Red thin and Black thin;

+

Red thick, Black thick, Blue thick;

Since it says it can measure up to 10A (with its internal shunt) I dont need an external shunt, right '

First question is: Can I power the ammeter (in the red and black thin wires) with the same power source i'm going to measure ?

Second how do I wire the power source, monitor and ammeter without worrying about the external shunt ?

If anyone can provide a wiring and a simple explanation I'd appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the voltage that you are measuring is within the 3-30 volt, then you can use the device's power supply to power the voltmeter/ammeter.

If you scroll down on the ebay link that you provided, it provides a diagram of how to wire the voltmeter.

If the monitor that you are measuring draws less than 10 amps, then you don't need a shunt.  There should be a label on your monitor telling you its power consumption and from there using Ohm's law you can estimate the amps it should draw and if less than 10 amps then no shunt needed.

Just ask if it is still confusing.

Good luck.

Comment: Yes, the monitor draws between 500mA and 800mA. What about the wiring of the thick wires, how to connect them? I'm confused because the eBay link I provided only gives instructions to wire with a shunt. If you could provide a diagram on how to wire the thick wires but without the shunt I'd appreciate.

Comment: @Carlcox89 - from looking at the diagrams I can see why there is confusion.  They make it difficult.  I have only wired these with a shunt.  It appears that the thick red wire connects to positive of load and thick blue wire to negative of load and it appears that thick black wire connects to negative of power supply to load.

Answer (score 0):

The wiring diagram is here: [Link](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/DC-0-100V-Red-Blue-LED-10A-Dual-Digital-Panel-Amp-Volt-Gauge-Voltmeter-Ammeter-I-/141382655856?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_3&hash=item20eb101f70), about half-way down the page.

Comment: And can I power the ammeter (the thin wires) with the same power source i'm trying to measure ?

Comment: @Carlcox89 yes you can. F. Bloggs, welcome to eesx and thanks for pointing the asker in the right direction. Since the question can be seen as not too device specific try to expand your answer, and avoid a link only answer. Links rot, ebay links rot even faster. You'll have my +1 if you improve your answer.